# GCC gives initializer element is not constant, ARMCC does not

Tags: c, gcc

In libfixmath there is [the following macro magic](https://github.com/PetteriAimonen/libfixmath/blob/83c5f4438ebc2e781b0f98e4612b56c75db59c9d/libfixmath/fix16.h#L303):

```
#define F16C(i, m) \
( (fix16_t) \
    ( \
      (( #i[0] ) == '-') \
        ? -FIXMATH_COMBINE_I_M((unsigned)( ( (i) * -1) ), m) \
        : FIXMATH_COMBINE_I_M((unsigned)i, m) \
    ) \
)
```

It is used like this, dozens of times:

```
F16C(3,1415)
```

To initialize various things, from structs to arrays and temporaries.

Works fine in ARMCC. But I'm migrating to ARM GCC, and there it gives me the following error, *but not on all instances*, mostly when doing const struct initializations.

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

Which has something to do with using non-constants as initializer. Which is understandable.
But this macro is given *two integer literals*. Can't get more constant than that!

Am I missing something, or is there an GCC Extension I'm not aware of to make this work?

Update: there is a `sizeof(#token)` in a [macro called by this](https://github.com/PetteriAimonen/libfixmath/blob/83c5f4438ebc2e781b0f98e4612b56c75db59c9d/libfixmath/fix16.h#L230).

> Note: in contrast to ARMCC, GCC does correctly resolve the F16() macro and doesn't create an fplib call. Just a heads up for those that find themselves with this problem in the future.

Comment: Why would you believe that using the `?` operator results in a constant expression suitable for use as an initializer?

Comment: According to godbolt, it [works in gcc 8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/P1e3Eb) but fails in 7.3.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Because C 2018 6.6 6 allows integer constant expressions to contain operators, including `? :`.

Comment: The macro converts `i` to a string (with `#i`) and then attempts to take its first character (with `[0]` in `#i[0]`). The integer constant expressions that compilers are required to accept are specified in C 2018 6.6 6, and using strings as operands is not included. Compilers may accept this (because 6.6 10 allows it, but does not require it), which can explain why ARMCC accepts it and old versions of GCC did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to godbolt, it [works in gcc 8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/P1e3Eb) but fails in 7.3.

However, if you replace `( #i[0] ) == '-')` with `(i) < 0`, then it works in [lower versions too](https://godbolt.org/z/zo4xKc).

I find it weird that the author of this library chose to use `( #i[0] ) == '-')` to test if the macro argument is negative, since it will fail if the parameter is not an integer literal.

**(Update)** According to OP's comment, the reason why `(i) < 0` cannot be used is that it needs to classify `-0` as negative too.

Here are some different approaches for GCC:

```
// does not work on gcc
#define IS_NEG(x) ((#x)[0] == '-')

// works, but fails the "-0" case
#define IS_NEG(x) (x < 0)

// works on gcc (although, it matches '-' at any idx)
#include <string.h>
#define IS_NEG(x) (strchr(#x, '-') != NULL)
```

Strangely enough, usage of `strchr` [seems to be allowed](https://godbolt.org/z/fdj9cx) in creating a compile-time constant on gcc 5.4 or newer.

Comment: It is quite weird and requires some roundabout thinking, so one has to suspect the author had something in mind beyond testing for negative values.

Comment: Does that work with `F16C(-0,5)` ? Also, it fails `F16C(1,00048)`....

Comment: @Jeroen3: ok, so the negative zero explains the reasoning. Why does `F16C(1,00048)` fail though?

Comment: Something to do with octals, makes sense. This macro is weird....

Comment: @Jeroen3: right, so the `F16C(1,00048)` call is supposed to create a fixed float literal for `1.00048`. Although `00048` is an octal literal, the expansion of `FIXMATH_CONVERT_MANTISSA` prepends `1` in `1 ## m ## ULL` so I don't think it should fail in this case?

Comment: @Jeroen3: anyway, it seems that `strchr` works in GCC, so I've updated my answer with this approach.